# html link to change page or just dynamic update the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I was looking up some document of google today and I found the page link just link to other url instead of replacing the information content in a div zone.  This raise some doubts in my mind: "should I just make several pages for each link instead of using ajax to update the div?"

My website has a div zone to show the content. When user hit the link btn, the details show up in that zone.

I expect someone could suggest me about the benefit to us dynamic replacing or I might follow the google document style Orz...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an application design style decision you have to make. Do you want it to be an ordinary web page or a single-page application?

Comment: it depends on what you're building. if some page sections are static while other sections are dynamic it will be easier to have your 'div zone'. This can be accomplished with a server-side templating engine or a front-end library like react or angular. If you're going to completely different pages then a link to an outer page is fine. It's really up to you

Answer (score 1):

*Single Pages*:

**Advantages**:

- Faster to load
- Easier to code

**Disadvantages**

- Time consuming to code
- If there are changes you would need to one by one edit every page
- Not good for a long run
- Storage Problems since you need a file for every page
- File structuring is harder

*Dynamic Pages*

**Advantages**

- Easier to manage, since you only need to check 1 file for a code
- More Uniformed, same as above
- Easy File Structure
- Storage Friendly, less files
- Good for the long run because it is easier to edit

**Disadvantages**

- Harder to code
- Slower compared to static pages
- Harder to debug if it is complex and you have many file connected to the file you are debugging

Honestly there are more advantages and disadvantages to this, but it is your call since some page needs to be static and some are better as dynamic.

You can also check this [link](https://www.weblinkindia.net/blog/static-vs-dynamic-website-advantages-disadvantages)

Comment: Wow, I guess SOE is a big problem for dynamic ones according to your link. No wonder the document is structured statically... And also, I notice that when I use my website, I try to click the back arrow which result in jump out of my website XD

Comment: SOE or SEO???. well if you jump from other websites unto your website, it surely will jump back to the other website which you visited first if you press the back arrow, that's just how browsers work.
You can mix dynamic and static web pages on your website since some pages are fine as static like the 'about us' page or 'contact us' if it is not saved from the database and hard coded, and some page are best as dynamic like the 'blog feed', the 'searched results page' and many more.

Comment: SEO Got it! and I also found the page changing lagging is kind of intolerable for me...

Comment: well the trick for the SEO of dynamic pages is on the link GET values, that' why you can search public Facebook post on Google works. Is that page dynamic?